# Uploading file to azure iis web app using ASP.net mvc fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, ftp

im using simple ASP.net app from Azure web service web app 
i have this code which supposed to enable me to upload file to the same server which i run the web app . 
like this :

```
 try
{

    FtpWebRequest r = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/myfiles/FTP");
    r.KeepAlive = true;
    r.UseBinary = true;
    r.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    r.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myapp\userA","password123");
    FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(source + "sourceFile.json");
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    fs.Close();
    r.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
    r.UsePassive = false;
    r.UseBinary = true;
    r.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
    r.EnableSsl = false;
    using (Stream requestStream = r.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }
    FtpWebResponse rs = (FtpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
    rs.Close();
catch (WebException ex)
{
    throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
}
```

2 strange things happning ,
 1. when i run the code from Visual studio locally i have no exception thrown 
but the file never created.
 2. when i run this code from my web app im getting :

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: do you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify a file name when you initialize a new WebRequest. For more information about how to upload file with FTP, please refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
FtpWebRequest r = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://waws-prod-hk1-021.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/myfiles/FTP/sourceFile.json");
```

[image]

> when i run this code from my web app im getting : 500 (Internal Server Error)

You could enable [remote debugging feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) to debug the code and troubleshoot after you deploy application to Azure app service.